# FlatList Slow and start flicking when many screens in their previous route.?

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-flatlist, react-navigation-stack

FlatList start flicking and slow when we navigate from one list to another (screen1-list ---->screen-normal ----> screen3-list).

The list on first screen works fine but when i go to the 3rd screen its will start flicking and crash sometime and lots of frame drops in system trace. But while navigating to 3rd screen if i clear the route then its behave normal.

Both the FlatList are very large, and I'm using pagination and the components are pureComponents.

"react-navigation": "^2.6.2",
"react": "16.8.6",
"react-native": "0.60.5",

Comment: You're using a very old version of React Navigation. You should upgrade.

Comment: after updating the react-navigation to "react-navigation": "^4.0.10",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.0.16", the problem is still same